# Cannot bind 127.0.0.123 to tcp socket python

Tags: network, python

I'm trying to learn TCP sockets for my project. I will be using them to transfer files between computers.

The server client combo copied from some tutorial runs fine as long, as the ip I'm trying to bound is `127.0.0.1`. When I change it to anything less standard, like 127.0.0.123 OSX says, that I cannot bind to this address:
`socket.error: [Errno 49] Can't assign requested address`

I have no problems on debian tough.

Server code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket

TCP_IP = '127.0.0.123'
TCP_PORT = 50050
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024  # Normally 1024, but we want fast response

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connection address:', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not data: break
    print "received data:", data
    conn.send(data)  # echo
conn.close()
```

Client code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket


TCP_IP = '127.0.0.123'
TCP_PORT = 50050
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGE = "message sent from client to server"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.send(MESSAGE)
s.close()
```

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the IP address of the computer the code is running on (aka `localhost`), 127.0.0.123 usually doesn't exist.

Comment: So why does this run fine on debian? Isn't it like loopback is /24 network for testing network apps offline?
EDIT: Actually, I believe it's not only /24 but /8

Comment: Different network stack, `ping 127.0.0.123` doesn't work on OS X either. If I remember correctly, the standard defines /8 as reserved for loopback, it doesn't mandate that every address is reachable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a Mac the loopback interface only has the 127.0.0.1 address configured. You could always add an alias to the IP you need:

```
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 127.0.0.123
```

Your python code worked for me then.

To delete the alias do the following:

```
sudo ifconfig lo0 -alias 127.0.0.123
```

---

To make this persistent over reboots create *org.local.localhost.plist* in /Library/LaunchDaemons/. 
Change the permissions with:

```
sudo chmod root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.local.localhost.plist
```

Open the file with

```
sudo nano /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.local.localhost.plist
```

and add the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>org.local.localhost</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/sbin/ifconfig</string>
        <string>lo0</string>
        <string>alias</string>
        <string>127.0.0.123</string>
        <string>up</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Finally load the launch daemon with:

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.local.localhost.plist
```

Comment: So this alias will work the same way it does under debian?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean. I've been able to add the alias and execute the python code, thus binding to 127.0.0.123? What does Debian do that you need?

Comment: Debian just allows me to bind 127.0.0.123, so I think the result is same :)

Comment: Just checked and Your solution works perfectly, thanks :)